# Igraph visualisation : color the nodes according to their centrality

Tags: r, igraph

I work on a connected network of 21 nodes and 44 valued links. As shown below:

```
    > E(G.final)
+ 44/44 edges from cc34dce (vertex names):
 [1] N --M  N --LS N --BT N --T  N --P  N --B  N --E  N --JL AN--A  PR--P  JB--J  JB--L. JB--LC JB--S  M --LS M --T  M --B 
[18] M --E  M --JL J --BT J --V  J --C  J --P  J --G  J --B  J --S  BT--V  BT--A  BT--C  BT--P  BT--S  BT--AL V --C  V --P 
[35] V --AL L.--S  T --B  T --E  A --C  C --B  C --S  C --AL B --E  B --S 
> V(G.final)
+ 21/21 vertices, named, from cc34dce:
 [1] N  AN PR JB M  LS J  BT V  L. LC T  A  C  P  G  B  E  S  AL JL
```

For the first one I managed to weight the size of the vertices to the Current-Flow Closeness Centrality I used.

```
centrality <- calculate_centralities(G.final, include = "Current-Flow Closeness Centrality")

V(G.final)$attribut.centrality <-unlist(centrality, use.names = T)

V(G.final)$attribut.centrality

plot(G.final,layout = layout_with_fr,vertex.color = "grey", edge.color = "black", vertex.label.family = "Times", vertex.label.color="black")
```

For the second one, I want to assign a color to the vertices according to their Barycenter Centrality measure. I succeeded in calculating this one and added it as an attribute of the vertices.

```
info.centrality <- calculate_centralities(G.final, include = "Barycenter Centrality")

V(G.final)$attribut.info_centrality <-unlist(info.centrality, use.names = T)

V(G.final)$attribut.info_centrality

summary(V(G.final)$attribut.info_centrality)
```

BUT I cannot find the syntax which allows to attribute different colors according to the following logic:
-a color for the measures lower than the 1st Quartiel,
-one for the measures between the 1st and the 3rd and
-a last one for the measures above or equal to the 3rd quartile.

Does anyone have a nice suggestion? Thanks in advance !

After a few hours of research and testing here is what I managed to do with the cartography and igraph packages. Probably less aesthetic than what was proposed afterwards!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with graphs, particularly plotting them, is easier with the `tidygraph` and `ggraph` packages. You can generate a much nicer plot too. Just `cut` the barycenters by their own quantiles

```r
library(igraph)
library(CINNA)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

as_tbl_graph(G.final) %>%
  mutate(closeness = unlist(calculate_centralities(G.final, 
                      include = "Current-Flow Closeness Centrality")),
         barycenter = unlist(calculate_centralities(G.final, 
                    include = "Barycenter Centrality")),
         barycenter = cut(barycenter, quantile(barycenter),
                          include.lowest = TRUE,
                          labels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"))) %>%
  ggraph(layout = "stress") +
  geom_edge_diagonal(color = "gray80") +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = closeness, color = barycenter)) +
  geom_node_text(data = . %>% filter(barycenter %in% c("Q1", "Q2")),
                 aes(label = name)) +
  geom_node_text(data = . %>% filter(barycenter %in% c("Q3", "Q4")), 
                 aes(label = name), color = "white") +
  scale_color_viridis_d(name = "Barycenter", direction = -1) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(8, 15), guide = guide_none()) +
  theme_graph() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible data inferred from question**

```r
df <- structure(list(from = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"AN", "PR", "JB", "JB", "JB", "JB", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"J", "J", "J", "J", "J", "J", "J", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", 
"BT", "V", "V", "V", "L.", "T", "T", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", 
"B"), to = c("M", "LS", "BT", "T", "P", "B", "E", "JL", "A", 
"P", "J", "L.", "LC", "S", "LS", "T", "B", "E", "JL", "BT", "V", 
"C", "P", "G", "B", "S", "V", "A", "C", "P", "S", "AL", "C", 
"P", "AL", "S", "B", "E", "C", "B", "S", "AL", "E", "S")), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), class = "data.frame")

G.final <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(df, vertices = unique(unlist(df)),
                                         directed = FALSE)

igraph::E(G.final)
#> + 44/44 edges from 7307c5d (vertex names):
#>  [1] N --M  N --LS N --BT N --T  N --P  N --B  N --E  N --JL AN--A  PR--P 
#> [11] JB--J  JB--L. JB--LC JB--S  M --LS M --T  M --B  M --E  M --JL J --BT
#> [21] J --V  J --C  J --P  J --G  J --B  J --S  BT--V  BT--A  BT--C  BT--P 
#> [31] BT--S  BT--AL V --C  V --P  V --AL L.--S  T --B  T --E  A --C  C --B 
#> [41] C --S  C --AL B --E  B --S

igraph::V(G.final)
#> + 21/21 vertices, named, from 7307c5d:
#>  [1] N  AN PR JB M  J  BT V  L. T  A  C  B  LS P  E  JL LC S  G  AL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Edit**

Here is an example of how you can add a size scale, a Brewer color palette and different edge thicknesses. There is no weight attribute in my example graph, so I have added a line of code to add random weights: clearly, you will need to delete this line to get your own weights to show:

```r
set.seed(1) # only used for reproducing random weights

as_tbl_graph(G.final) %>%
  mutate(closeness = unlist(calculate_centralities(G.final, 
            include = "Current-Flow Closeness Centrality")),
         barycenter = unlist(calculate_centralities(G.final, 
            include = "Barycenter Centrality")),
         barycenter = cut(barycenter, quantile(barycenter),
                          include.lowest = TRUE,
                          labels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"))) %>%
  activate("edges") %>%
  mutate(weight = runif(44)) %>% # delete this line to use your own weights
  ggraph(layout = "stress") +
  geom_edge_diagonal(aes(width = weight), color = "gray80") +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = closeness, color = barycenter)) +
  geom_node_text(data = . %>% filter(barycenter %in% c("Q1", "Q2")),
                 aes(label = name)) +
  geom_node_text(data = . %>% filter(barycenter %in% c("Q3", "Q4")), 
                 aes(label = name), color = "white") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette  = "Greens", name = "Barycenter") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(8, 15), name = "Current-Flow\nCloseness") +
  scale_edge_width_continuous(range = c(0.2, 2), name = "Edge weight") +
  theme_graph() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it does indeed seem to work very well! And even simpler! I'm just wondering how to indicate in the legend that the variation in vertex size corresponds to X values and X values of Current-Flow Closeness Centrality. How to show the proportionality of the area of the circles? Would you have an idea with tidygraph and ggraph packages ?

Comment: Is it possible to choose the colors assigned? With a palette and the brewer.pal function, for example ? I don't see where to insert the argument

Comment: I am surprised also the links are not automatically validated with these packages. I tested this way: geom_edge_diagonal(size = G.final$weight,color = "gray80") but it doesn't work; any ideas?

Comment: @NA_ the size legend is actually there by default - I removed it with the argument `guide = guide_none()` inside `scale_size_continuous` because I thought it looked better without it. You can just remove this to see the legend.

Comment: @NA_ you can choose any colors you like using the various ggplot color scale functions - for example `scale_color_brewer` or `scale_color_manual` instead of `scale_color_viridis`

Comment: @NA_ you can easily change the visual edge attributes too - you just have the syntax wrong. I will create an edit to show how, along with the other changes mentioned above

Comment: Thank you very much for these tips! I continued to search on my side and arrived at a correct but less aesthetic result with the igraph and cartography packages; I edit my message to show you

Comment: @NA_ from looking at your previous questions, you might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) useful for getting the best out of the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Of course, I understand better and better how to present my problems in order to hope to be helped. I tested again the two proposals you made to compare them and it does not work anymore (including the first one)

The console returns 
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,

Comment: @NA_ I'm not sure why that happened; the above code is fully reproducible as a reprex given the graph object I created above (obviously I don't have your actual graph). Have you tried restarting R?